# Clean Install and RAM?

Tags: system-installation

Hello Folks I'm new to Linux and was wondering about the RAM and which version to install 32 or 64 bit? The following is the RAM on my system - 2,048 (1,024 + 1,024) MB, DDR2 RAM (800 MHz).

Cheers and thanks for any reply it's appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the 32 bit version, since you have only 2 Gb of RAM.
32 bit systems can use all of the RAM until 4 Gb, so unless you are planning on upgrading you RAM in the future, i would suggest you get the 32 bit version since it's usually more stable.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate your time in answering my question, very helpful.